# Watermark image

Tags: graphics, tutorials, watermark

Please note I'm new to LaTeX so don't know much about it (yet).  I've looked on-line about how to add a watermark image but don't know how to do it.  I've seen sites that show something about it but they seem to be aimed at people who know how to add extra packages, something I don't know how to do (yet).

Does anyone know of a site or tutorial that takes 'newbies' through the process on a step by step basis?  I will need o have text easily readable on the page so the colors as I want to have it centered on the page both horizontally and vertically but automatically adjusted to fill the page to the margins up but keep the aspect ratio of the original image.

Comment: I would use TikZ for this but I'm really blinded since I use it for many things and there can be even easier solutions. Please check first [page 200 of the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) such that we can understand if this suggestion is indeed something related to your question.

Comment: @Einherjar, Do you want to add watermark to an image (eps/pdf) or to a text file ? . Kindly make the question clear. You have many watermark packages in ctan. The best start point is to search for packages at http://www.ctan.org/search/ they have lot of examples and usage

Comment: How about the first three tex.sx results in http://lmgtfy.com/?q=tikz+watermark

Comment: @jmc: Wow!! Thanks for showing me something new...

Comment: @percusse Yes, that's what I have in mind but with a bitmapped image I have JPEG), not a Latex generated graphic.

Comment: @Einherjar Can you make up an example one page document and the image you want to make a watermark with? It can be any image such that we can synchronize our efforts. You can edit and put these details into your question.

Answer (score 15):

How about a simple example like the following? Create the image file, name it `test.png`, then compile the document via `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics{test.png}}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

There is also the [eso-pic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package, but I have not used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=\includegraphics{yourimage.png}}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

You can also adjust other traits of your image such as transparency, scale, color in the argument of the command. All available options can be found in the package [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/background?lang=en).

```
\backgroundsetup{contents=\includegraphics{yourimage.png}, scale=1, opacity=0.75}
```

The `scale` option will set the scale of the background image. The `opacity` in this case will be changed to 0.75 (defaults to 0.5).