# Repeated text watermark on the whole page

Tags: output, watermark

I'm want to put a repeated short text on the whole page as watermark... 
I've read the `xwatermark` guide but didn't find anything helpful.

Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: Related: [Watermark image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61137/5764).

Answer (score 5):

How's this for starters?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\testh
\newlength\testw
\newcommand{\shorttextwatermark}{draft }
\setlength{\testh}{\heightof{\shorttextwatermark}}
\setlength{\testw}{\widthof{\shorttextwatermark}}
\newwallpaper[allpages,tilexsize=10\testw,tileysize=10\testh,boxalign=left]{\shorttextwatermark}
\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanx azetina thats exactly what im talking about... i actually got an error: no pagespecifier in watermark attributes:||allpages, tilexsize... I will have to read the manual. Thanx again you helped alot:)

Comment: OK i took a look at xwatermark package docu... it works when i replace "allpages" with "firstpage"... looks goooooooooood:)

Comment: is there any manual where took all this from... i would like to bring some space between the lines and displace the lines...

Comment: @anton: To achieve the spacing, add an option like `tileyoffset=1cm,` to the `\newwallpaper` options. All the options are described in the package documentation, but the example I made more or less by trial and error..! Once you feel your question has been suitably answered, consider accepting it.

Comment: for `IEEEtran` class, the `allpages` paramter doesn't seem to work, its always only on the first page. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: @bonanza: I am unable to reproduce your problem at the moment. Changing the example to use the `IEEEtran` class, and adding appropriate new pages and dummy content gives the correct result for me. Can you clarify whether these steps work for you, and precisely what steps you have tried that don't work?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the text in the background, then you can use *xwatermark* package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\thispagestyle{empty}
% This is all you need for the wallpaper:
\newwallpaper[%
  page=1,fontfamily=put,textcolor=blue,fontsize=1cm,textscale=1,
  textalign=center,textangle=0,tilexoffset=0pt,
  tileyoffset=0pt,squaretiles,boxalign=center,
]{Draft}

% Let me add a box at the center of page 1:
\def\boxa{%
  \xwmcolorbox[framesep=4pt,innerframerule=4pt,outerframerule=2.5pt,
    fillcolor=black,innerframecolor=white,
    outerframecolor=red,height=0mm,
    textalign=center,width=.25\paperheight
  ]{%
    \scalebox{1.0}{\textcolor{white}{Draft Box}}%
  }%
}
\newwatermark[page=1]{\boxa}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]