# Package Pagegrid - Change color of helpgrid

Tags: color

I want to put a grid in the background of every page (for use in classroom). I found the package `pagegrid`. I can change the color of the red/blue grid, looks beautiful, but I need to change the color of the help lines to light-gray, otherwise it's too dark to use for my students.

Another possibility would be to get rid of the helplines alltogether, but this didn't work either.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[step=5mm,firstcolor=gray,arrows=false]{pagegrid}
\pagegridsetup{top-left}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I found a solution now. Thank you. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311402/graph-paper-as-an-underlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311402/graph-paper-as-an-underlay)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graph paper as an underlay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311402/graph-paper-as-an-underlay)