# Watermark over Images & Portait to Landscape in LaTex

Tags: landscape, watermark

I'm having problem with two separate things.

1. The first is, that I can't put a watermark over the images. As you can see in the comments, I have tried many different ways, but none of them works correctly or do what I want. And I can't understand why (this is my first document in LaTeX).
2. The second thing I need to do, is to change a certain page in my document, from Portrait to Landscape. But the thing is, that I want the whole page to change into Landscape. Meaning the Header and Footer too, and thus I don't want to rotate the page. I have also tried different ways but none of them works as wanted.

I have simplified my code so you can only see one page and not the whole document. Can anyone please help me?

```
\documentclass[10]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} %Pictures 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Header-Footer

\usepackage{pdflscape} %Landscape
\usepackage{lscape} %Landscape

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} %Page Margins


\usepackage{draftwatermark} %Works but does not set watermarks over image
%\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark} %Doesn't work
\usepackage{xcolor} %Color Manipulation

%\newsavebox\mybox %Doesn't work
%\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=red,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};} %Doesn't work
%\newwatermark*[ allpages, angle=45, scale=6, xpos=-20, ypos=15]{\usebox\mybox} 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132582/transparent-foreground-watermark

%\SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics{draft.png}} %Doesn't work
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61137/watermark-image

\graphicspath{{C:\Path...}} %path for pictures

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}

\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Header  \\ Date}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Footer}}
\fancyfoot[R] {\textbf{•}\\ \thepage} % \textbf{•} is empty, therefore No. of page is in 2nd line

\begin{document}

%\newwatermark*[page=2-\lastdocpage,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{\textsc{draft}} %Doesn't work
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118939/add-watermark-that-overlays-the-images

\SetWatermarkText{\textsc{draft}} %Works but does not set watermarks over image as wanted
\SetWatermarkScale{3} %Works but does not set watermarks over image as wanted
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.75} %Works but does not set watermarks over image as wanted

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.80]{11.png}}
\caption{Caption rotates with image as wanted}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the portrait to landscape change, have a look at the `geometry` package. It allows to create a new page layout and resetting it.

Comment: @Huang_d from (http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf), I read that papersize-related options and paper size options can’t be changed with geometry package (I also tried it to be sure). But thank's anyway!!

Comment: I see. I just remembered it allowed `\newgeometry` and `restoregeometry`. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: @Huang_d thank you very much for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using a combination of package `typearea` from the KOMA-Script bundle and package `geometry`. Note that you can not use `\newgeometry` to change the margins of the resulting landscape page. Its bottom margin will be about twice as large as its top margin.

To get the correct head and foot width on the landscape page I would use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr` for header and footer.

Then an additional foreground layer can be defined and added to all layer page styles (`@everystyle@`) or to a selected one (eg. `scrheadings`). I presume that the text below the watermark should be still readable, so I use a `tikz` node with `opacity=.3`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  headheight=24pt,footheight=24pt,% as suggested by scrlayer-scrpage
  areasetadvanced
]{typearea}% load this before geometry!!
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\savegeometry{default}}

\newcommand\switchtolandscape{%
  \clearpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}\recalctypearea
  \areaset{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4cm\relax}{\dimexpr\paperheight-7cm\relax}%
}
\newcommand\switchtoportrait{%
  \clearpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}\recalctypearea
  \loadgeometry{default}%
}

\usepackage{tikz}%loads graphicx and xcolor

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{Header\\Date}
\cfoot{Footer}
\ofoot{•\\\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\bfseries}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  contents={\tikz\node
    [minimum width=\layerwidth,minimum height=\layerheight,text=red,opacity=.3]
    {\rotatebox{45}{\scalebox{8}{\textsc{Draft}}}};%
  }
]{watermark.fg}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{watermark.fg}% comment this to remove the watermark

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\Blindtext

\switchtolandscape
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{center}
    \fbox{\textcolor{yellow!20}{\rule{.9\textwidth}{.9\textheight}}}
    \caption{Caption rotates with image as wanted}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\switchtoportrait

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you  very much!! It works perfect!! But I have one more question. How can I remove the blank page that was created before the landscaped page? (Of course I didn't create that page and I can't find a way to do that).

Comment: Probably the picture is too high to fit on the page. Shrink its height a bit.

Comment: I tried, but the blank page still exists. I also tried \nopagebreak but as you can image, nothing changed. I have found something about the \afterpage package and I'm trying to find more about it.

Comment: I removed the blank page, by deleting \clearpage from \newcommand\switchtolandscape{}. Thank's again!!